# Selenium chrome web-driver inconsistency in selecting a dropdown element

Tags: java, angular, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am using selenium for automation, but getting inconsistent results. If there are 10 repeated tasks to be performed around 6-8 are running as expected about 2-3 are failing the main reason for this issue is stale element or unable to find the element on the web page

I have tried multiple settings for chrome browser

```
driver = new ChromeDriver(cop);
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(4, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("estblshmntSel")));
dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("estblshmntSel")));
```

**Error Message**
setting establishment paramsstale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
(Session info: chrome=84.0.4147.125)
(Driver info: chromedriver=84.0.4147.30 (48b3e868b4cc0aa7e8149519690b6f6949e110a8-refs/branch-heads/4147@{#310}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Comment: it's possible the DOM is still updating...probably appending items to the select you are trying to work with.  You can either add a plain old sleep, or function-ize the calls which sometimes produce stale element exceptions and then try/catch driver calls.  When a stale element exception is caught, you re-run the function.  (The stale element exception is great for knowing when the DOM is still being updated... so you re-grab the elements.)

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the dropdown element

```
dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("estblshmntSel")));
```

in every iteration of the repeated task. Everytime you do a task, the DOM gets updated and hence the old element, instantiated earlier results in StaleElement. I have faced this issue multiple times while using loops in a selenium.